# How count number of operations/computational cost

Tags: performance

When calculating the computational cost, what is really relevant: Assignations, Comparisons, Operations (products, sums,...), or do I have to count everything?

Thanks.

Comment: it depends, are you from the management or the PR department ?

Comment: If you want to estimate the energy cost, you essentially have to count every instruction. If you want to calculate the time cost, even counting every instructions is insufficient; you need a performance model for the processor. If you merely want to calculate a O-notation cost, it suffices merely to count loop iterations (since the cost of a single iteration is essentially a constant). If you want the cost in the setting of a classroom assignment, check the assignment details or ask the instructor. Note that operations in a high-level programming language are not the same as instructions.

Comment: Are you analyzing an algorithm for big-O? Then count some basic operation like comparisons. If you're in the real world, don't waste time calculating, just time it (a watch will do). Then if you want it to be faster, [*here's a video of how I do it.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U) There are numerous questions here of the form "Which is faster, ++i or i=i+1?", when there a big-old fat PRINTF or NEW sitting in the middle of the code.